# CSS lower-right position dependant on the page height

Tags: css, css-position

See http://jsfiddle.net/2A3xZ/ for the issue I'm facing. The image should be on the lowest right corner **after** scrolling, not in the lowest right corner of the viewport first drawn.

Using

```
.someclass {
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

and then containing the divs inside each other does not work for some reason (the entire image just disappears). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`.  Here is the fiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/VbV3P/

Edit: After OP's comment:

You should be able to apply `position: relative;` to your body.  Please see the following:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="corner">
    <img src="http://wtactics.org/wiki/images/2/2b/Box.png" />
</div>this
<br>is
<br>the
<br>site
<br>content
<br>which
<br>will
<br>cause
<br>the
<br>page
<br>to
<br>scroll
<br>vertically
<br>because
<br>of
<br>its
<br>amount
<br>of
<br>lines.
<br>that
<br>is
<br>expected
<br>behaviour
<br>and
<br>working
<br>as
<br>is
<br>should
<br>be.
<br>however,
<br>the
<br>box
<br>on
<br>the
<br>lower
<br>right
<br>corner
<br>should
<br>be
<br>at
<br>the
<br>current
<br>page's
<br>lowest
<br>corner
<br>depending
<br>the
<br>page's
<br>height,
<br>not
<br>just
<br>in
<br>the
<br>corner
<br>of
<br>the
<br>first
<br>drawn
<br>viewport.
<br>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
.corner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keW4P/

Comment: I wouldn't want the image to "slide" along while scrolling down, but just to appear on the lowest corner when the viewer reaches there. Is there another alternative?

Comment: That does it, thanks! It's not working with my project page, but that's caused by something else now and I'm off to find what that might be...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the image is just before the end tag of the body. Give it a value of position: absolute; right:0; bottom:0;

Comment: Image _is_ just before the end tag, not that it would matter as `position: absolute` overwrites any other alignment - as seen on my jsFiddle (you can change the <div> part to the end, it changes nothing).